# Comparing ArcGIS Data Interoperability with FME or GeoKettle?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fme-form, dwg, data-interoperability, geokettle

In order to import/extract data from tons of DWG files, I'd like to know experiences with ArcGIS Data Interoperability, and its strong points versus FME or GeoKettle.

Comment: Related Question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18018/data-interoperability-or-fme-esri-edition +read comments Note: once you have FME Desktop [Workbench] you will not want to use any other ETL.

Answer (score 3):

Arcgis Data Interoperability Extension (ADIE) "is" FME.
That is to say. Esri has implemented the FME engine into their extension.
FME Desktop for ArcGIS is a product sold by Safe software which adds more functionality to ADIE and can be "extended" to ArcGIS.

Extended is a term that Safe Software uses to describe hooking or linking the software together.

My experience is that if you know the data well "**dwg layer names, color assignments, object data, feature types/layers**" you will be able to navigate and get some good usable data out with fme or the ADIE (easily).
If the data is much standardized I prefer to use Autocad map3d to export.
With it you can create epf files which pre-define the export parameters and allow a bit more (autocad type) selection tools. You can probably do most of that in fme desktop "if" you know a lot about the data in the dwg.

But for interactive data browsing and export creation I prefer Map3d.

Also note that FME desktop for ArcGIS can be "extended to AutoCad Map3d. So you can import/export any of the types available in fme desktop directly from autocad as you can in the interoperablity extension.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experience. The option of using Map3D could be interesting.